# Thermal relief for thick PCB traces

Tags: thermal, kicad, trace, pad

A PCB trace that carries considerable current (~5 Amps) needs to be wide, on the order of 4 mm. I am concerned that this wide and thick (70 mil) trace may cause problems during hand soldering, but cannot figure out a way to make thermal relief for the pads in Kicad. It is easy for copper fills, but that would mean drawing the outline for each trace by hand. Is there a less laborious way?

Comment: A half decent iron won't have any trouble with a trace like that.  Simply observing good soldering technique using appropriate methods (clean tip, flux, good quality solder and a bit of experience) will suffice.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I don't have much experience with PCB design. Do you think that soldering will not present problems even if I connect with duplicate traces on both sides of the board?

Comment: I think you need more practical soldering experience before getting involved with the more unusual aspects of PCB design.  You can't beat experience. :)  A good way to learn is to take apart old broken junk from ebay and attempt to desolder/reattach parts by hand.  It doesn't matter if the parts work afterwards, but just learn how thermal mass can affect your iron's ability to get heat into a PCB.  It's also great fun and you can harvest parts this way to re-stock your workbench.

Comment: I have no time for that, that's why I am asking for help on stackexchange from those who do have the experience.

Comment: Okay, then see my first comment.

Comment: try soldering on a thick aluminum substrate, for power LEDs for practice :), use liquid flux and clean surfaces helps immensely

Comment: Well, it looks like the question is moot because soldering is possible with good iron. Probably will withdraw the question tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases:

- the current needs to run through the pad: you don't want thermal relief
- the current doesn't need to run through the pad: there is no need to connect the pad directly on top of the trace

Comment: The current does need to flow from the pad into the trace, but I think thermal relief is acceptable because the gap is very thin and there may be many spokes